# Is it possible to generate a list of functions in Python?

Tags: python

I am new to python, and require to generate something like the following, a list of similar functions using a loop and store them in a list.

I mean something along the lines of the following:

```
funcs = []
for i in range(1,11):
    def temp():
        print i
    funcs.append(temp)
```

Of course I know this won't work since its only temp being stored throughout the list and doing something like

```
funcs[3]
funcs[7]
```

will give

```
10
10
```

instead of

```
3
7
```

I don't wan't to use lambdas as the functions have to be a little more complex than what they allow.

Comment: I really don't see how you could do that, but are you sure your functions cannot either have parameters to unify them into one or be wrote as one liners ?

Comment: @asimoneau - no, they can't

Comment: Just to clarify why the linked question answers your question.  What you were doing does make separate functions.  However, they were all working with the same version of `i`.  The linked question tells you how to avoid that.